# Steam no longer recognizing games in drive F

Tags: steam

I installed games onto another internal drive, and since yesterday steam seems to have forgotten that games are installed on that drive, I don't want to download all the games again, help?

Answer (score 0):

I went to settings, downloads, steam library folders, and then "add library" and re-selected my old folder. All the games are back now.